# embedded flash youtube video via swfobject.jsaudio only in firefox, works in ie6-ie7

Tags: javascript, swfobject

I am trying to play and control a youtube video via javascript using the swfobject.js library. The video plays fine in IE6 and IE7, but I only get audio using firefox. I don't even get a flash object showing up, and the innerHTML attribute doesn't give me any .

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the code examples from the YouTube API page? They seem to work (most) of the time when you recreate them on your own server, but can be a bit buggy.

It took me a while to make sense of it, but setting the

var atts = { id: "myytplayer" }; and understanding that it replaces the div took some head scratching.

Demo
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html?playerType=embedded&playerVersion=as3

Function Reference
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html